# Full date format about date command in bash

Tags: bash

I am recently checking GNU manual frequently.
Here is one thing I am not able to figure out at all.

About date command:
`date %F`

Doc states that

> full date in ISO 8601 format; like ‘%+4Y-%m-%d’ except that any flags
> or field width override the ‘+’ and (after subtracting 6) the ‘4’.

What does this sentence mean?
What are flags and field width?
Why should we include the plus sign `+` in `%+4Y-%m-%d`?
`date +%4Y-%m-%d` prints `2021-03-02` but `date +%+4Y-%m-%d` prints `%+4Y-03-02`

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify  flags or field width `%F`, it subtracts 6 from the width (because the `-%m-%d` part of the date always takes 6 characters) and uses that as the width of the `%Y` part of the date, and the options replace the options to `%Y`.

So `%12F` is equivalent to `%6Y-%m-%d`. The flags don't include `+` and the width 12 becomes width 6 for the years.

Flags and field widths are a GNU `date` extension. The flags are documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Padding-and-other-flags.html#Padding-and-other-flags)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think the problem is that I have no idea what flags and field width are. I guess the number between `%` and `F` specifies the field width.

Comment: `date +%12F` prints `  2021-03-02` with 2 spaces padded at the beginning of the string. `date %6Y-%m-%d` prints `002021-03-02`. So I think they are not equivalent.

Comment: You might have noticed that format in the doc includes a `+` between `%` and `4` in `%+4Y-%m-%d`. What is the meaning of this plus sign? I also tried it in terminal like `date +%+4Y-%m-%d` but it prints `%+4Y-03-02`. Is it a legal syntax for `date` command?

Comment: See the `date` documentation. The plus is how you specify the format; it's kind of like an option, except it's not.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I am following `date` documentation. Plus should appear at the beginning of the format, right? But it appears after the first `%` which makes the syntax invalid I think.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice the typo. Yes, that would appear to be invalid, though I guess maybe the string formatting library might accept an optional sign in front of the field width. (Could be platform-dependent, too.)

Comment: @tripleee So as to string formatting library, I also tried printf function by `printf '%(%+4Y-%m-%d)T\n'` with no luck. The number of year not printed. I believe that it should be a typo now. But I still get the point of the sentence from this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The string formatting library would not know anything about the `date` formatting codes like `%Y` etc; but the `date` program might be replacing those with `%i` or whatever and then calling the C string formatting library on that. This is an implementation detail anyway, so not something you should rely on, even if you figure out how it works right now on your particular version of the software.

Comment: @krave It's not `printf()` it's `strftime()`

Comment: @tripleee `date` uses `strftime` to format dates, not `printf`

Comment: Hi both, I finally know why there would be difference between doc description and the behavior on my machine. I wll write an answer this question by my own to finish it up.

Answer (score 1):

To summurize the reason why `date +%+4Y-%m-%d` prints `%+4Y-03-02` instead `2021-03-02` is that the version of coreutils installed on my machine is 8.30 which is different from the version of the web manual which is 8.32.

And according to coreutils release announcement for 8.31 [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils-announce/2019-03/msg00000.html)

> 'date' now supports the '+' conversion specification flag,
> introduced in POSIX.1-2017.

`date` starts to support '+' flag since version 8.31.

Tips for others who found GNU manual mysterious:

1. Check the version of web manual you are reading first.
2. Check the version of coreutils installed by `apt-cache policy coreutils`
3. Use `info <command>` to check for doc locally first to find the correct manual responding to your command version if you don't feel like to update coreutils.
4. If you are curious since which version the changes made, visit https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils-announce/ to browse the release announcements.
5. If you'd like to use newer version of GNU package and to find the correct Ubuntu version to install, say coreutils, you can visit this [page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/). Under the section of Search package directories, input `coreutils`, select Distribution as `any`, press search button and there you go. You can find the version of Ubuntu
   with associated version of coreutils.